# GameEngine: KX_BlenderMaterial vs KX_PolygonMaterial

Tags: materials, game-engine, shaders

I have a question about the material types in the game-engine.

e.g.:

[2.66 Blender API - KX_PolyProxy(SCA_IObject)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_66_4/bge.types.KX_PolyProxy.html#module-bge.types)

[2.66 Blender API - name ~ The material of the polygon.](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_66_4/bge.types.KX_PolyProxy.html#bge.types.KX_PolyProxy.material)

- When is the material a BlenderMaterial object ?
  and
- when a PoylgonMaterial object?
- What are the internal differences?

Thank you.